# Enabling default persistence on existing ignite cluster

Tags: java, ignite

Our application uses ignite to share data between different services. We habe a couple of caches und queues. Currently some of the caches are persisted using a second data region. This works fine. A new requiredment is to persist the items in the queues.

Because queues always use the default data region I assumed if I enable persistence on that region the queue content should be persistet. But this works just for the caches and not the queues. The queues still lose its content if the cluster shuts down. The log shows that persistence is enabled on the default region.

The thing is if I reset the cluster (deleting the ignite home folder) the queues get persistet fine.

I tried renaming the queues, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ignite mailing list had an idea that worked.

Changing the group name in the CollectionConfiguration did the trick. It seems the name doesn't just has influence the partition placement but also influcens how data is persistet/read from disk.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Ignite doesn't really support changing type of data region or having mixed persistent-not persistent nodes for the same data region.

You can try resetting nodes one by one (removing their work dir before restart). Please try this in testing first.

Comment: All nodes would have the same setting. A "rolling update" won't work because we also updating ignite itself.

Comment: You can rolling update your data regions first, make sure queues now work as expected, and then do proper upgrade.